# Margin and padding not working css

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple website for the very first time and I've decided to animate my links. I used the code from a github I found on the internet (http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) and applied to 4 links. The problem is that two of them got a strange bottom margin of one px. On top of that, 'margin' and 'padding' only seems to work 30% of the time, so I can't use neither to fix this.

My html code for the links:

```
  <span class="sidebar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="empresa" href="#">A empresa</a></li>
  <li><a class="servicos" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
  <li><a class="contato" href="#">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
<aside>
  <p>lol</p>
  <p>test</p>
</aside>
</span>
```

And the button animation code:

```
.home {
   background-color: silver;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-transition-property: color;
   transition-property: color;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

 .home:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #1a0f3a;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

 .home:hover, .home:focus, .home:active {
    color: white;
}
 .home:hover:before, .home:focus:before, .home:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

The bugged links are "empresa" and "contato", as you can see on the screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX063.jpg

Comment: I can't understand your problem, is this what you are trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/1crm4mcs/

Comment: Sorry, I should've added a screenshot. I'll do it now

Comment: @dan_s Done. As you can see, the "empresa" and "contato" buttons have an unwanted bottom margin. The weirdest thing is that it only appeared after I added the animations.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to rephrase your question into "How can I animate my buttons like this?" Plugins tend to over-do things. How do you want your buttons to be animated? (I advise you to keep it simple. No one likes elaborate animations anymore these days.)

Comment: It's a simple animation, it just slide a purple color from the left when you hover it